# Why is Pic^0(C) of a curve C a variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, definitions, reference-request

Let $C$ be an abstract non-singular curve.

I'm having a hard time finding a reference for why $\text{Pic}^0(C)$ is a variety.

Any pointers towards a reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Mumford's "Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface"

Comment: Milne's course on Abelian varieties gives the classical proof due to Weil. Another proof (using GIT) is in Mukai's book on Invariants and moduli. 

Comment: The book of Polishchuk "Abelian Varieties, ..." is good.